# Spinner selected Item Issue

Tags: android

I have made the two fragment.
Payment Fragment and other is Add Payment fragment.
Payment Fragment contains the shop Spinner in witch multiple shops user select the shop the history of payment show if the add payment button click the add fragment screen show add the payment and submit the payment after submit the payment the screen back to the Fragment list. My problem is after back the fragment list screen the selected shopSpinner value change show the first spinner value not show user selected spinner.
PaymentFragemt

```
public class PaymentFragment extends Fragment {
    View myView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getShop;
    String shopId;
    Fragment fragment;
    int totalpayment,shopOrderTotalPayment;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPaypent;
    ListPaymentHistoryAdapter listPaymentHistoryAdapter;
    Spinner spinnerShop;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_listview, container, false);
        final Context context = myView.getContext();
        final DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
        spinnerShop = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.searhshop);
        final TextView totalpaymentTextView=(TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.totalPayment);
        final TextView totalOrderpaymentTextView=(TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.totalOrderPayment);
        final TextView leftpaymentTextView=(TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.leftpayment);
        final ListView lvpayment=(ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.payment_listview);
        getShop=JavaHelper.setShopSpinner(spinnerShop,myView);
        spinnerShop.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                shopId= getShop.get(position).get(Shop.getColId());
                /*Get total Payment*/
                totalpayment= JavaHelper.shoptotapayment(Integer.parseInt(shopId),context);
               /* Get Shop Order Payment*/
                shopOrderTotalPayment=JavaHelper.shopOrderTotaPayment(Integer.parseInt(shopId),context);
                /*Set Left Payment*/
                leftpaymentTextView.setText(Integer.toString(shopOrderTotalPayment-totalpayment));
                totalpaymentTextView.setText(Integer.toString(totalpayment));
                totalOrderpaymentTextView.setText(Integer.toString(shopOrderTotalPayment));
                /* Show Payment List History*/
                String[] projectionPayment = {
                        Payment.getColpayment(),
                        Payment.getColcreated_at()
                };
                String wherclause=Payment.getColshopId()+"="+shopId;
                getPaypent= myDBHelper.thread_safe_select(Payment.getTablName(),projectionPayment,wherclause,null,null,null);
                if (getPaypent!=null){
                    listPaymentHistoryAdapter=new ListPaymentHistoryAdapter(myView.getContext(), getPaypent);
                    lvpayment.setAdapter(listPaymentHistoryAdapter);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"NotSelectClick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        ((Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.paymentAdd)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("shop_id",Integer.parseInt(shopId));
            fragment=new AddPayment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            String title = "Add Payment";
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();
            }
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Add Payment Fragment

```
public class AddPayment extends Fragment {
    View myView;
    Context context;
    DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    Fragment fragment = null;;
    int colorID;
    Bundle bundle;
    long leftPayment;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_add,container,false);
        myDBHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
        context=myView.getContext();
        myDBHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
        final EditText addPaymentEditText=(EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.paymentAdd);
        final TextView leftpaymentText=(TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.leftpayment) ;
        bundle=getArguments();

        if (bundle!=null){
            final int shopId=bundle.getInt("shop_id");
            leftPayment=JavaHelper.shopOrderTotaPayment(shopId,context)-JavaHelper.shoptotapayment(shopId,context);
            leftpaymentText.setText(Long.toString(leftPayment));
            ((Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.addPaymentbtn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String getPayment=addPaymentEditText.getText().toString();
                    Payment payment=new Payment(getPayment,shopId,JavaHelper.getCurrentTimeDate());
                    if (myDBHelper.thread_safe_insert(Payment.getTablName(),payment.getContentValues() ,context) != -1) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Add Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Some thing wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                    fragment=new PaymentFragment();
                    String title = "payment";
                    JavaHelper.hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        addPaymentEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.v("beforetextChange","textchange event");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.v("ontextextChange","textchange event");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (!(editable.length()<=0)){
                    Long enterPayment=Long.parseLong(editable.toString());
                    leftpaymentText.setText(Long.toString(leftPayment-enterPayment));
                }
                else {
                    int length=editable.length();
                    Log.v("length",Integer.toString(length));
                }
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using the `onSaveInstanceState` functions to save its current dynamic state. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Comment: Please post your code.